# yum install sbt on CentOS 6.8

Tags: installation, sbt

1)After the yum install, I typed **sbt** in home directory. It downloaded a whole lot of packages. But it also downloaded Scala version 2.10.0. I already have a more recent SCALA installed...2.12.X

2)I also get the error
[error] **IllegalArgumentException**: requirement failed: Source file **"/usr/bin/jmc.ini"** does not exist.

3)I have created a file called build.sbt
When I run **$ sbt build** I get the following error
[error] Not a valid command: build

4)ALSO, every time I run the SBT command, it tries to download packages...is this correct ?

Comment: i have the latest 1.8.X version of JAVA installed.

Comment: I have created a file called build.sbt
When I run ...>>$ sbt build << I get the following error
[error] Not a valid command: build
[error] Not a valid key: build (similar: loaded-build, loadedBuild)
[error] build
---->ALSO, every time I run the SBT command, it tries to download packages...is this correct ?